# How to output to dict type in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data, and I would like to output it in a dict type, but after trying various ways, I get an error, so I asked this question.

**s**

```
"report": [
            999,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            ......
]
```

**s.index**

```
"report": [
            "2020-03-27T00:00:00",
            "2020-03-28T00:00:00",
            "2020-03-29T00:00:00",
            "2020-03-30T00:00:00",
            "2020-03-31T00:00:00",
            "2020-04-01T00:00:00",
            "2020-04-02T00:00:00",
            "2020-04-03T00:00:00",
            .....
]
```

↓Originally, this is how I want the output to look like

```
"report": [
            "2020-03-27T00:00:00":999,
            "2020-03-28T00:00:00":0,
            "2020-03-29T00:00:00":0,
            "2020-03-30T00:00:00":0,
            "2020-03-31T00:00:00":0,
            "2020-04-01T00:00:00":0,
            "2020-04-02T00:00:00":0,
            "2020-04-03T00:00:00":0,
            .....
]
```

```
test = {s[i]: s.index[i] for i in s}
```

I have tried this, but I get the error **index 999 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 344**.

Comment: you should do test = {s[i]: s.index[i] for i in range(len(s))} I think

Comment: Please check the length of both `s, s.index` as you are getting index error, there might be some missing data

Comment: @Leander
Thank you for your answer. When I tried it, I got the error "keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not int64", how can I improve this?

Comment: As you are in pandas, why not just run `s['report'].to_dict()`?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I misunderstood what you're trying to do. Does RJ's suggestion work?

Comment: @Leander
As I asked on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66547739/for-some-reason-the-fordoes-not-work-properly/66548052#66548052 `{s[i]: s.index[i] for i in range(len(s))}` doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Yea, I'm stupid, sorry :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to do it using pandas: `test = s.to_dict()`

You could also do:

`test = dict(zip(str(s.index), s))`

or

`test = {x : y for x, y in zip(str(s.index), s)}`

or

`test = {str(s.index[i]) : s[i] for i in range(len(s))}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have tried all of them, but they all give me the error "keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Timestamp".
Why do you think this is?

Comment: Convert the dates to strings first.

Comment: To access the values using pandas method, use `test[pd.Timestamp("2020-03-27T00:00:00")]`. All other methods, you can just pass strings. For example,` test["2020-03-27T00:00:00"]`