# For some reason, the fordoes not work properly

Tags: python, pandas

[How to output to dict type in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66545650/how-to-output-to-dict-type-in-pandas)

I just asked a question here, and I found out a little bit about the cause of the problem, but I don't know how to solve it, so I asked.

This is what the data originally showed.

```
"report": {
    "2020-3-27": 999,
    "2021-2-18": 1221,
    "2021-2-22": 1201,
    "2021-3-2": 1004,
    "2021-3-3": 491,
    "2021-3-5": 168
},
```

The previous data was divided into date and data parts, and the missing parts were repaired.

```
mappedData = {
            f"{record['created_at__year']}-{record['created_at__month']}-{record['created_at__day']}":
            record['time__sum']
            for record in data
}

s = pd.Series(mappedData)
idx = pd.date_range(s.index.min(), s.index.max())
s.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(s.index)
s = s.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
```

**s**

```
"report": [
            999,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            ......
]
```

**s.index**

```
"report": [
            "2020-03-27T00:00:00",
            "2020-03-28T00:00:00",
            "2020-03-29T00:00:00",
            "2020-03-30T00:00:00",
            "2020-03-31T00:00:00",
            "2020-04-01T00:00:00",
            "2020-04-02T00:00:00",
            "2020-04-03T00:00:00",
            .....
]
```

```
test = {s.index[i]: s[i] for i in range(len(s))}
```

I want this result to look like this for statemenet

```
"report": [
            "2020-03-27T00:00:00":999,
            "2020-03-28T00:00:00":0,
            "2020-03-29T00:00:00":0,
            "2020-03-30T00:00:00":0,
            "2020-03-31T00:00:00":0,
            "2020-04-01T00:00:00":0,
            "2020-04-02T00:00:00":0,
            "2020-04-03T00:00:00":0,
            .....
]
```

If you run the previous code, you will get the error message "keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not int64".

If I try it with `test = {s[i] for i in range(len(s))}` or `test = {s.index[i] for i in range(len(s))}`, it works, but if I try it with `test = {s[i] for i in range(len(s))}`, it doesn't work. The result of repairing the first missing data is not reflected and the following data is returned.

I thought the error "keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not int64" was caused by the difference in the number of `s` and `s.index`. Is this correct?
Is this correct? Also, how can I improve it?

I'm sorry I'm a beginner, but I would appreciate it if you could tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you want to get a dictionary out of your Series.
Well, there is a function for this [pd.Series.to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html)

```
test = s.to_dict()
```

If you really want to loop over the Series, then I would use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of `range(len(s))`.

```
test = {s.index[i]:v for i, v in enumerate(s)}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I don't want to extract a dictionary from a series, I want to create a dict type like { s : s.index }.
But `{s[i]: s.index[i] for i in range(len(s))}` doesn't work well.